# Clearing caches of all apps

Tags: android, cache-control

I know there exist a manifest permission **"CLEAR_APP_CACHE"** but I don't know how to use it. Can anyone tell me how to clear the caches of all installed applications?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's meant to be this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.remote.command import Command
self.driver.execute(Command.CLEAR_APP_CACHE)
```

found similar at
https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/trunk/py/selenium/webdriver/common/html5/application_cache.py

but I get this when I try to use it with the Firefox webdriver

> WebDriverException: Message: 'Unrecognized command: DELETE /session/6086cb3e-2397-470b-919c-ee36a3bb5d32/application_cache/clear'

Answer (score 0):

From [this android-developers thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/WLumh5zq18U):

> CLEAR_APP_CACHE probably shouldn't have been in the SDK if the API it protects isn't in the SDK. :)